# Why is Python trying to automatically encode my Unicode string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I'm trying to read a bunch of e-mail messages from files that are encoded in ISO-8859-1, then write (parts of) them out to a JSON file with UTF-8 encoding. I've currently got a program that reads them and produces objects with `str` type properties containing the various fields of the message. I want to convert these `str` strings (encoded bitstrings) to `unicode` strings (abstract Unicode objects) so that I can later re-encode them with UTF-8 when I write out the file. So I use the `decode` method of `str`, like this:

```
msg_dict = {u'Id' : message.message_id.decode('iso-8859-1'), 
                u'Subject' : message.subject.decode('iso-8859-1'), 
                u'SenderEmail' : message.sender_email.decode('iso-8859-1'),
                u'SenderName' : message.sender_name.decode('iso-8859-1'),
                u'Date': message.date.isoformat()}
```

According to the documentation I've read, `decode` should take the `str` object, interpret its bytes according to the given encoding, and return a `unicode` object representing those characters. But when I run my code, I get this error:

```
  File "/home/edward/long/path/omitted/dumpMails.py", line 38, in <module>
    u'Subject' : message.subject.decode('iso-8859-1'),
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How could I be getting an **encode** error when I call **decode**? My best guess is that Python has decided to automatically convert the returned `unicode` back to a `str`, using the default encoding. But why is it trying to do this? Is it something to do with putting `unicode`s in a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will automatically try and *encode* a value *if it is not yet a byte string*. You cannot decode a Unicode string, after all, so Python tries to be helpful and tries to make it a bytestring *first*.

In other words, the string is *already decoded to unicode*:

```
>>> decoded = u'åüøî'
>>> decoded.decode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You'll either have to test if it is already a Unicode string, or if it is *always* a Unicode string, just don't try to decode it.

Incidentally, you'll see the inverse problem if you have a byte string that you are trying to encode; Python will implicitly decode such a value first, so that it has a `unicode` object to encode for you:

```
>>> encoded = u'åüøî'.encode('utf8')
>>> encoded.encode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note the *decode* keyword in that error message.

Comment: You're right, I guess the documentation for the code that produced the `message` objects (which I didn't write) lied about the type of the `subject` property. This is why I hate duck-typed languages: I don't know whether `subject` is a `str` or `unicode` until runtime, and if I guess wrong it will still try to use the variable as the wrong type.

Comment: @Edward: you can always use `isinstance(obj, str)` to see if it requires decoding first.